# How to update FullCalendar events in Symfony

Tags: symfony, fullcalendar, riot.js

Hello, everybody.
 I am using fullcalendar in my symfony    project(Symfony + RiotJS).
 I want to load the events dynamically when    I press 'prev' or 'next' button. 
So I make a new calendar when the    page is mounted and set the calendar events as 'null'.
 As you can see    on the code, I called the loadItems() function to load the events    again when I press 'prev' or 'next' button.
 But I can't sure how to    update the events of calendar in the loadItems() function.
 I'd really    appreciate if someone knows how to fix it.
 I will wait for reply.
Thanks.

```
           onMounted() {
                self = this;
                let calendarEl = this.$('#calendar');
                this.state.calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin ],
                    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                    headerToolbar: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek'
                    },
                    buttonText: {
                        today: 'Heute',
                        month: 'Monat',
                        week: 'Woche',
                        day: 'Tag',
                    },
                    datesSet: function() {
                        let view = this.currentData.dateProfile.renderRange;
                        let start = view.start.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
                        let end = view.end.toISOString().substring(0, 10);

                        if (start != getSearchParam('begin')) {
                            updateSearchParam('begin', start);
                            updateSearchParam('end', end);
                            self.loadItems();
                        }
                    },
                    events: this.state.events,
                    initialDate: getSearchParam('date', '') ? getSearchParam('date', '') : this.moment().format('Y-MM-DD'),
                });
                this.state.calendar.setOption('locale', 'de');
                this.state.calendar.render();
                updateSearchParam('date', '');
                this.update();

                this.loadItems();
            },
```

And this is the loadItems() function.

```
            loadItems() {
                this.state.loading = true;
                this.update();

                if (this.state.request) {
                    this.state.request.abort();
                }

                this.state.request = this.API.get('/events', this.getParams());

                this.state.request.then(response => {
                    this.state.items = response.data.items;
                    this.state.filteredItems = null;
                    this.state.total = response.data.total;
                    this.state.events = [];

                    response.data.items.forEach( item => {
                        let event = {
                            id: item.id,
                            title: item.event.name,
                            start: this.moment(item.begin).format('Y-MM-DD'),
                            end: this.moment(item.end).format('Y-MM-DD'),
                            backgroundColor: item.event.type.bgColor,
                            borderColor: '#ffffff',
                            textColor: this.getTextColor(item.event.type.bgColor),
                        };

                        this.state.events.push(event);
                    });

                    this.state.loading = false;
                    this.update();


                    //after I gets the events I want to update the events of calendar here
                    //this.state.calendar.refetchEvents();
                    this.update();

                    this.state.request = null;
                });

                return this.state.request;
            },
```

Comment: Sorry, everyone. I found my solution.

Comment: I just used calendar.setOption('events', this.state.events);

Comment: Write an answer with well description how it solved the problem so it could help others with similar issue.

Comment: `I want to load the events dynamically when I press 'prev' or 'next' button.` See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function .... create a dynamic feed to the calendar and it'll update automatically from the source data whenever the date is changed (which can be for more reasons than just the buttons being pressed). You [asked this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72788116/using-prev-and-next-buttons-fullcalendar) and I already explained this to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just focused how to update events when I press the 'prev' and 'next' button.

I searched a lot about the method and there were many solutions.
For example:

- `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvents', events)`
- `$('#calendar').fetchEvents()`

But these methods are not working on my problem.

Finally, I found a simple method.
It is a `setOption()` method.
As you can see on my above code, there are options like 'datesSet' and 'events'.
The 'datesSet' option is called everytime when I press the buttons (prev, next, today, month, week and etc).
And the 'events' option is for events to show on the current calendar view.
I used setOption() method like this.

```
this.state.calendar.setOption('events', this.state.events);
```

It worked well for me.
I suggest the people who read my question and answer, to read the tutorials and documentations carefully.

Fullcalendar is really well-built javascript package and we can use it very simply.